# How to run tests using buildbot without compiling/buildning the project

Tags: buildbot

HI I have 2 questions regarding Buildbot:

1. I want to run tests I wrote, without compiling the project ( i have a different mechanizm of compiling/building the project) but I don't find any way to configure that. The Buildbot documentation explains how to build and only then run tests. I want to skip the build part. Anyone has tried to do this?

2.How to configure the buildbot to work with local repository. I have a computer which syncs the repository with the main one once a day at night, and I want to run Buildbot on this computer, and buildbot should run tests locally. (Tests are a separate project within the same solution )

My environment is: Win7, Visual Studio, git repository, tests are a separate project within the same solution.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

1) buildbot just runs a sequence of steps. They can be whatever you want. If you don't have a build step, then you don't need to run that.

2) The `Git` step just pass the `repourl` it is passed to `git clone`/`git fetch`, so if the repository is local, you can just pass it the path.